# react-router without node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to use react-router without installing node.js?

As I see this is that there is no way to use react router without using node.js. As I see it we should install node.js and use npm to install react-router. And only then we could use it.

Is react-router is node.js component only or it can be downloaded separately?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider checking [react-router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router#installation)?

Comment: oh, that's my fault. It's because I saw this in the Installation block: Using npm: 
$ npm install --save react-router

Comment: but there is a CDN available: `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using provided CDN. My fault that I haven't read the docs.

Comment: I recommend you to follow the webpack and npm install path as specified in this tutorial. I was not a node guy before. But node helps you in managing imports pretty well. 
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-building-a-react-js-app-basic-routing-with-react-router

Comment: Yes, I started to use node.js yesterday and now I am node guy :)